# How to get data from a custom dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

I Have a dialoge box in my code, that when i click a button in Main activity it pops up, this dilog box is like this :

[image]

I want to put String data from "Enter NUmber" and "Enter Name" Test box to a viewText in Main Activity, I don't know how to transfer this value.
my part of code which pops up dialog box is this :

> btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main0.this);
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.number);
              dialog.setTitle("Save New Number");
              dialog.setCancelable(true);   
              dialog.show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
Button saveButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String name = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameText)).getText().toString();
        String number = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberText)).getText().toString();
    }
});
```

(Add it in your `onClick` method)

Comment: this is fffffff briliant, why did i not think of this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the textView, where you want to show the text, is in the same Activity, where the dialog pops, define a String like:

```
       String text="";
```

then, get the textView (inside onClick before dialog.show())of Your in xml defined dialog layout.

```
   TextView yourTextView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(YourTextViewId);
   text = yourTextView.getText();
```

After that, You can set the text to your TextView where you want to show the input:

```
   yourShowView.setText(text);
```